# Jquery creates new element but won't delete this element after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have a problem with my script. I want to create dynamic objects, if I push on "Create New Element" the new object will be created but if I push on remove, it does not work. Why? Thank you.

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 
  // Create new Object inside of #content
  $("#wrapper > #taskbar > #create_new_element").click(function(){
   $("#wrapper > #content").append('<div class="new_object"><p>New Object</p><a class="remove_object">Remove</a></div>');
  });
 
  // Remove an Object inside of #content
  $("#wrapper > #content > .new_object > .remove_object").click(function(){
   $(this).closest('<div class="new_object"><p>New Object</p><a class="remove_object">Remove</a></div>').remove();
  });
 });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">

 
  <div id="taskbar">
   <p id="create_new_element">Create new Element</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content"></div>



    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129794/how-to-remove-an-element-that-is-added-dynamically-in-javascript

Comment: `adding eventlistener on dynamic divs` have a look at SOs js top100 questions...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an element that is added dynamically in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129794/how-to-remove-an-element-that-is-added-dynamically-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for elements created dynamically.

```
$(document).on('click',"#wrapper > #content > .new_object > .remove_object",function(){
    $(this).closest('.new_object').remove();
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Read more about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: I tried this in a jsfiddle and it threw me an error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div class="new_object"><p>New Object</p><a class="remove_object">Remove</a></div>`. I had to target the the class `.new_object` inside of `.closest()` for it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/cg4ouyrm/1/. I think I must be doing something wrong. +1 from me still though =)

Answer (score 0):

You have bind events to the newly created elements after they are created

check the following snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Create new Object inside of #content
  $("#wrapper > #taskbar > #create_new_element").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper > #content").append('<div class="new_object"><p>New Object</p><a class="remove_object">Remove</a></div>');
    bindRemoveEvent();
  });

  function bindRemoveEvent() {
      $(".remove_object").on('click', function() {
        // console.log(this);
        $(this).closest('.new_object').remove();
      });
    }
    // Remove an Object inside of #content

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<body>
  <div id="wrapper">


    <div id="taskbar">
      <p id="create_new_element">Create new Element</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content"></div>



  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps